# Debugging through WSL GDB in VSCode occupies all the memory until the process gets killed

Tags: gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-debugger

I am trying to run in debug mode (GDB) a program through WSL in VSCode.

I have build in debug mode, I am able to run GDB and put breakpoints in the command line, but I cannot do it with VSCode, because when I launch a debug session, I can see that all the memory I have assigned to WSL is occupied until, eventually, after some minutes of nothing, GDB gets killed.

In the VSCode Debug Console I get the following error:

```
ERROR: GDB exited unexpectedly. Debugging will now abort.
The program 'blablabla' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

While in the VSCode Terminal:

```
Killed
[1] + Killed                     "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-fw2yczts.a4s" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-xjgjw3cq.kho"
```

My setup:
VSCode version: 1.79.2 x64
System version: Windows 11 Pro
WSL version: Ubuntu 2
GDB version: Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04

I have also tried to run GDB in command line with the VSCode argument `--interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm}` and it worked fine.

The problem does not occur when trying to debug a simple Hello, World! program.

I tried to increase the memory size of WSL, but the memory is still increasing up to its limit.

I am reasonably sure that the execution of my program itelf should not use so much resources.